# Markov inequality for stochastic processes?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I was wondering if the Markov inequality $P(X\geq a)\leq \frac{E(X)}{a}$ holds for stochastic processes. In other words, if we know a stochastic process $(X_t)_{0\leq t\leq T}$ satisfies $E\int_0^T |X_t| dt<\infty$, does it imply $\sup_{t\in[0,T]}|X_t|<\infty, a.s.?$

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_t(\omega)=\frac1 {\sqrt t}$ for $t>0$ and $0$ for $t=0$. Then $E\int_0^{T}|X_t|dt= 2T<\infty$ bus $\sup_t |X_t|=\infty$ a.s.